# IN clause and Group by

Tags: postgresql

Table : Subjects

```
ID   SUBJECT_NAME COLLEGE NAME  SYEAR
101   EA           AAA           2016
102   EA           AAA           2016
103   EL           BBB           2016
104   EP           CCC           2016
```

Table : Courses

```
SUBECT_ID  COURSE_NAME  SYEAR
104         EP           2016
101         EA           2016
```

I have to select the records from SUBJECTS table that meets the below condition.

Subject_name that occurs more than once in Subjects table but do not have an entry in COURSES table. In the above example, I have to get only EA with ID 102.

```
select * 
from subjects 
where id not in ( select id from courses) 
  and ??
```

I am not sure how to include aggregate function in this query?

Answer (score 0):

Just add on to your WHERE clause with another condition. The subquery

```
 SELECT subject_name FROM subjects HAVING count(*) > 1 GROUP BY subject_name
```

Will return subject_names that appear more than once in your `subjects` table, so:

```
 SELECT id
 FROM subjects
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM courses)
     AND subject_name IN (SELECT subject_name FROM subjects HAVING count(*) > 1 GROUP BY subject_name)
```

You could also do this Window functions:

```
 SELECT id
 FROM (SELECT id, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY subject_name) as subject_name_count FROM subjects) t1
 WHERE subject_name_count > 1
     AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM courses)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I  just noticed that the Subjects table is Year,College-specific. I modified the table in my original post. I will have to get the ID ( Unique) from the SUBJECTS table, not the SUBJECT_NAME. Below query should give me the subjects that appear more than once based on syear and college name. SELECT subject_name,syear,college_name FROM subjects HAVING count(*) > 1 GROUP BY subject_name,syear,college_name; How do I get just the ID from the SUBJECTS table to include it in the main query?